# Form validations to display the duplicate data field to be highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form field where the user enters data. If the user has entered a duplicate data which is already stored in the database and I have done it so to detect it's a duplicate data. But I want to make the field in a form in which the user enters duplicate data to be displayed red showing that this username already exists along with the field which he has entered duplicate data highlighting red. I have already written a JavaScript function to fetch all the data from database and it is doing so. It's not able to highlight the field red in which user has entered duplicate data.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'user.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .buttonalign{
                    margin-top: 20px;
                }
</style>       
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class= "content" style="z-index: 1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <form action="/auth/add_users" method="post" name="Add_Form">       
                <h3 class="text-center">Add User</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Username </h4>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control Email/Username" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" required="true" autofocus="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Password </h4>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control Password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required="true"/>            
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Email </h4>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control Email/Username" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required="true" autofocus="" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4> Site_url </h4>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control site_url" name="site_url" id="site_url" placeholder="site_url" required="true" autofocus="" />
                </div>
                <div class="buttonalign">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content" style="z-index: 999; position: absolute; right: 240px; top: 10px;" >     
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" id="box" style="display:none;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-target="#box" data-dismiss="alert">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">X</span>
                </button>
                    Subscribers
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <div id = "show-json-result"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" id = "userid" value="{{current_user.id}}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$( "#username" ).focusout(function() {
    username = $(this).value;
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       url: "/auth/get_users",
       data: { username: "username" }
    }).done(function( response ) {
        <!-- console.log(":::::"); -->
       if(response == "username"){
       console.log($username);
         $("username").borderColor = "red";
       }
    });
});

$( "#email" ).focusout(function() {
    email = $(this).value;
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       url: "/auth/get_users",
       data: { email: "email" }
    }).done(function( response ) {
       if(response == "email"){
         $("email").borderColor = "red";
       }
    });
});

$( "#site_url" ).focusout(function() {
    site_url = $(this).value;
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       url: "/auth/get_users",
       data: { site_url: "site_url" }
    }).done(function(response) {
       if(response == "site_url"){
         $("site_url").borderColor = "red";
       }
    });
});

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  $("username").borderColor = "red"; is wrong , you can define  an id for that elements and use

```
 $("#username").css("border-color","red");
```